# Is there a way to make an equivalent of the onValue() firebase function in a JS class?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developping a game's prototype with js and firebase
To avoid having to import all the functions of firebase on each file, I created a class gathering all the functions I need:

firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = { ... };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getDatabase();
export const auth = getAuth();
export default app;
```

services/DatabaseService.js:

```
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { ref, get, set, update, remove } from "firebase/database";

class DatabaseService {
    get = async (_ref = "") => {
        let output;
        await get(ref(db, _ref)).then((snapshot) => {
            output = snapshot.val();
        });
        return output;
    }

    create = async (_ref = "", _content) => {
        await set(ref(db, _ref), _content);
    };

    update = async (_ref = "", _content) => {
        await update(ref(db, _ref), _content);
    };

    remove = async (_ref = "") => {
        await remove(ref(db, _ref));
    };
}

const DB = new DatabaseService();

export default DB;
```

I make a little example for you
example.js :

```
import DB from "./services/DatabaseService";

const roomRef = "rooms/42534";

//Create a new room with name, owner and a list of player
await DB.create(roomRef, {
  name: "NicolAme's Room",
  owner: 0,
  players: {
    0: {
      pseudo: "NicolAme",
      score: 0
    }
  }
});

//Change the name of the room
await DB.update(roomRef, {
  name: "Best Room"
});

//Log the room's content
console.log(await DB.get(roomRef));

//Delete the room after 10 seconds
setTimeout(async () => {
  await DB.remove(roomRef);
}, 10000);

function App() {
  return <>
    <p>Sample</p>
  </>
}

export default App;
```

So, here is my question :
I want to make an equivalent to the `onValue()` firebase function, which do a call each time the reference is updated. **Is there a way to make a listener like this one in a class ?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`setters` and `getters`](https://javascript.info/property-accessors) are used for. Below is an example using classes, but object literals can also use the `get` and `set` keyword.

```js
class ObserverableObject {

  constructor(name,listener) {
    console.log(listener);
    this.name = name;
    this._prop = null;
    this._propUpdated = listener;
    console.log(this);
  }
  
  get prop(){
    return this._prop;
  }
  
  set prop(newProp){
     //console.log(this,this._propUpdated);
     this._propUpdated(newProp);
     this._prop = newProp;
  }
}

const obj = new ObserverableObject('test', (propValue) => {
  console.log("prop changed to",propValue);
});
console.log(obj);
obj.prop = 2;
console.log(obj.prop);

obj.prop = 3;
console.log(obj.prop);

obj.prop = 4;
console.log(obj.prop);
```

Notice, how the listener is passed when object is created. This gives you flexibility to decide what you want to happen when the property is changed.

The property `_prop` cannot be named same as `prop`, because then you have multiple variables of same name. It is a convention to prefix `_`.

You can use something similar for `onValue`

Comment: I'll see what I can do with this, thanks

Comment: @NicolAme sure. It this helps you please accept/upvote the answer to complete this.